# What is the proper way to write an accompaniment part without using instruments? (Vocals Only)

Tags: chords, harmony, melody, accompaniment, choral

I really want to be able to write songs without the need of using an instrument.
At first I was thinking it was as simple as starting with a drone in order to keep the lead voice in tune, but a great music stack exchange user pointed out to me that a drone would only really help with writing monophonically. In other words, he pointed out that it isn’t just about staying in tune and if I am writing something traditionally harmonic it would be better to use chords.

So essentially, what I want to do first is properly create accompaniment, without using an instrument (Vocals Only).

The two concepts i’ve arrived at are:

1. Try and create/hear a chord progression in my head as I write the lead vocals
2. Use a DAW or looper and record myself singing the root notes of the chord progression

And so lastly, with that second idea, would just the root notes of the chord progression be enough for accompaniment?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150554/discussion-on-question-by-lecifer-what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-an-accompanime); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a musical notation software program that features playback of audio and/or MIDI samples for several instruments to compose songs without resorting to an instrument. Some known examples are Sibelius, Finale, Guitar Pro and possibly others.

I personally have used Guitar Pro for years to compose music that mostly (but not always) revolves around guitar, for example. Composing with such programs allows you (the composer) to hear the playback of what you write as you compose. It is possible to compose without resorting to any instrument whatsoever. I do it quite often when composing for instruments that I do not own.

Having said that, I do think there are advantages on having your instrument with you, such as:

- Exploring melodies/harmonies in your own creative way/playing. I personally usually start composing by writing something that I came up with in the guitar, for example (but not always). I found over the years that just playing with your instrument is a powerful tool for creativity in composing.
- Cross-checking if the parts you are composing are indeed possible to play on the instrument. For example, this is key when composing for classical guitar and you are writing the fingerings on the sheet. Playing is really the only way to make sure something that you wrote is playable.